# I facing a Next.js styling issue with autofilled input fields.Chrome autofill doesn't apply background color (rgba(35, 31, 44, 0.7)) on page refresh

Tags: css, google-chrome, next.js, autofill, chakra-ui

Hello [Community/Forum Name],

I'm encountering a styling issue in a Next.js application related to input fields during autofill. Here's a brief overview:

Problem:
After saving a username and password in Google Chrome, upon page refresh, the autofilled username and password are shown in the input fields, but the background color is not as expected. Instead of using the specified background color (rgba(35, 31, 44, 0.7)), the input fields have a default white background.

Code:
Here is an excerpt of the code related to the input fields:

```
<Input
            px={"1vw"}
            h={"5.3vh"}
            bg={"rgba(35, 31, 44, 0.7)"}
            border={"1px solid #286F64"}
            borderRadius={{ base: "9px", "2xl": "15px" }}
            focusBorderColor="#286F64"
            fontSize={{ base: "10px", "2xl": "16px" }}
            color={"#ffffff"}
            _hover={{
              bg: "rgba(35, 31, 44, 0.7)",
            }}
            _placeholder={{
              color: "#ABABAB",
              fontSize: {
                base: "10px",
                "2xl": "12px",
              },
              fontWeight: 400,
              fontFamily: "Poppins",
            }}
            type="email"
            {...register("email", registerOptions.email)}
            placeholder="Enter Your Email"
          />
```